# When is this integral convergent?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-integration

Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Consider the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}}{1 + e^x} dx,$$ for which values of $a$ is this convergent? 
Is it right to say that $a$ has to be purely imaginary?

I have been staring at this for way too long, so I need some reassurance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part of the denominator can you ignore for large positive $x$, and which for negative $x$ of large absolute value?

Comment: If $x \rightarrow +\infty$, then denominator goes to $+ \infty$ and therefore, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ has to be bigger than zero. For negative $x$, $a$ has to be smaller than zero.

Comment: No, you need to take into account how fast the denominator grows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will look more familiar after a change of variables: set $y=e^x$. Then the limits become $0$ and $\infty$, and $dy/y = dx$, so the integral is
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^{-a-1}}{1+y} \, dy $$
Near zero, this integrand looks like $y^{-a-1}$, which has finite integral when $\Re(a)<0$. Near $\infty$, the integrand looks like $y^{-a-2}$, which has finite integral when $\Re(a)>-1$. Therefore the whole integral converges when $-1<\Re(a)<0$.

Comment: Good call on the change of variables, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 3):

As $x$ approaches $\infty$, we have

$$\frac{e^{-ax}}{1+e^x}\sim e^{-(a+1)x}$$

Thus, at the upper limit, we require that $\text{Re}(a+1)>0 \implies \text{Re}(a)>-1$ in order for the integral to converge.

---

As $x$ approaches $-\infty$, we have

$$\frac{e^{-ax}}{1+e^x}\sim e^{-ax}$$

Thus, at the lower limit, we require that $\text{Re}(a)<0$.

---

Thus, the integral converges for

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{0>\text{Re}(a)>-1}$$